# How to return error to the client client without making node server crash?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I have a route in a node server. When the request fails, I need to send back an error that I can easily catch in my front-end.

Basically, I do something like this:

```js
// server
app.get("/user/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const user = User.find(req.params.id)
    return res.status(200).json({user});
  }
  catch(err){
    throw new Error("error.user.route")
  }
});


// front
function fetchUser(id){
  return api.get("/user/" + id)
  .then(res=> res.data.user)
  .catch(err=> err.message)
  }
  
// somewhere in the dom
error && error.message
```

It works fine, I can pass clear error messages to the client, but when the server throws an error, it also stops. In local development it's perfectly fine to debug, but I can't have this behavior in production.

I've tried to simply send a `new Error("my message")` instead of throwing, but it doesn't land in the `catch`. I could send `res.json({error: "my message"})`, but I'd like to avoid handling errors with conditions in my frontend.

Is there a way to make sure an error in node always lands in the catch of an api call without making the server crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it`s better to send status code to frontend
https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/

```
 app.get("/user/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try{
     const user = User.find(req.params.id)

     if(!user) {
       res.status(404).json({error: "User not found"});
     }
    
     return res.status(200).json({user});
  }
  catch(err){
    return res.status(500).json({error: "my message"});
  }
});
```

And add default error handling in express https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#the-default-error-handler

Comment: Thanks! By adding a correct http error code, the error ends up in the client `catch` without making the server crash. However, I can't access the error message. I've wrote `.catch(err=> console.log(err))` but I only receive a built-in error message `Error: Request failed with status code 400` instead of my custom message. I've tried to create the error in two ways: `res.status(400).send(new Error('error.type.user'));`  and `res.status(400).json({error: 'error.type.user'});`. None of them work.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 what library do you use for sending requests from frontend to backend? Axios? If axios, your custom message will be at path ```err.response.data```, where err is catched error object.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above, you need to setup an error handler. I would also suggest to add the following helper to your code:

```js
export function fail(message, statusCode = 500) {
    const error = new Error(message);
    error.status = statusCode;
    throw error;
}
```

then you can do the error handler something like this:

```js
server.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  const status = error.status || 500;
  const serverSide = status >= 500;

  // This is not a production way to do logging
  console.error(error);

  let message = error.message || getErrorForCode(status);
  if (serverSide && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    message = 'Internal Server Error';
  }

  res.status(status).send(message);
});
```

Then you can do:

```js
app.get("/user/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  try{
    const user = await User.find(req.params.id);
    if (!user) fail('Not found', 404);
    res.json({user});
  }
  catch(err){
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Note: no need for `.status(200)` in your code: `.json(..)` sets 200 automatically; also you missed `await` :)