# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning Persists Even After Chaining a .catch()

Tags: node.js

My system consists of an Angular UI and a Node API. The UI submits a file to the API for processing, then gets the result back. This all works - however - the API sometimes fails at processing unexpected data.

I want to be able to catch the error(s) when they arise, stop execution so they won't screw up the UI, then send a message back to UI.

Here is my code so far:

```
const IncomingForm = require('formidable').IncomingForm;
asynch function myApi(req, res)
{
    try             // (1)          
    {
        var form = new IncomingForm(...);
        form.on('file', async(field, file) =>
        {
            const [result] = await sometimesBad(inParam);   // (2) attach .catch(...);
            ...
            res.send({goodFinal});      // execution should not reach here if error occurs before
        });
        form.on('end', ()=> {})
        form.parse(req)
    }
    catch (erApi)   // (3)
    {
        ... // (4)
    }
}

async function sometimesBad(x)
{
    try     // (5)
    {
        ... lines of code could have run-time error depends on x ...
        return goodResult;
    }
    catch(err2)     // (6)
    {
        ... // (7)
    }
}
```

**Currently, after hours of [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=(node%3A16376)%20%5BDEP0018%5D%20DeprecationWarning%3A%20Unhandled%20promise%20rejections%20are%20deprecated.%20In%20the%20future%2C%20promise%20rejections%20that%20are%20not%20handled%20will%20terminate%20the%20Node.js%20process%20with%20a%20non-zero%20exit%20code.&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS824US824&oq=(node%3A16376)%20%5BDEP0018%5D%20DeprecationWarning%3A%20Unhandled%20promise%20rejections%20are%20deprecated.%20In%20the%20future%2C%20promise%20rejections%20that%20are%20not%20handled%20will%20terminate%20the%20Node.js%20process%20with%20a%20non-zero%20exit%20code.&aqs=chrome..69i57.483j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and trial and error, I:**

- am able to send a message back by chaining a `.catch()` at `(2)`
- am unable to stop the execution via any combination of `(1), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7)`, including the use of `next()`, `throw new Error()`, `await Promise.reject()`, `return Promise.reject()`.
- am always getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.`

*Node version: `14.9`*

**Update**: In addition to accepted answer, there is no need to have `(5), (6), (7)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code if `(2)` throws the error indeed is not handled. To handle it, you need to wrap the code inside `async (field, file) => ...` into `try / catch`, similar to how you did on the top level of middleware, and inside the catch you do `next(error)`. Also add default error handler after all routes in your app. See [How to return error to the client client without making node server crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244710/how-to-return-error-to-the-client-client-without-making-node-server-crash/67245268#67245268) regarding that.

Comment: `form.on('file', async(field, file) =>` is what I missed! Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

You can stop `unhandledRejection`(s) from crashing your app by handling them. However, if you fail to handle them using catch blocks, you can also watch for [events on the process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection).

Code Example [from the Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection):

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
  // Application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});

somePromise.then((res) => {
  return reportToUser(JSON.pasre(res)); // Note the typo (`pasre`)
}); // No `.catch()` or `.then()`
```

Alternatively, you can make your `sometimesBad` function return a `Promise`, which would cause all errors happening inside the `Promise` body to be thrown, which can then be handled in the catch block of the caller.

Comment: The doc suggests to attach a `.catch()` to the Promise which is implented as `(2)`. Alternatively, because `async` wraps a function to be a Promise. So `async sometimesBad()` is a Promise in my code.